# How do I split a string in Java8?

Tags: java

I want to split the string `"004-034556"` into two strings by the delimiter `"-"`:

```
part1 = "004";
part2 = "034556";
```

That means the first string will contain the characters before `'-'`, and the second string will contain the characters after `'-'`.

I also want to check if the string has `'-'` in it.

Comment: can you specify what you are trying to do?

Comment: `"after 9k request I got this following problems: Connection refused"` -- This could be explained by Google protecting itself, because it considers your program to be performing a [denial of service attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack), if it does 9000 HTTP requests. However, that does not explain the segmentation fault.

Comment: `strlen(get.c_str())` should be `get.size()`.

Comment: If you're getting a segfault, that seems like a perfect use case for a debugger.

Comment: @SW3RD It wasn't an attempt to explain your crash, just trying to help you write better code.

Comment: @SW3RD: I am not that familiar with OpenSSL, but I agree with David Schwartz that the segmentation fault could be related to calling `SSL_library_init();` concurrently from several threads. I believe that you should only call it only once at the start of your program, before creating any threads.

Comment: Note that `SSL_read` may also return a negative value, to indicate an error. In the line `while(SSL_read(ssl,buffer,BUFFER_SIZE - 1) != 0){`, you are incorrectly treating negative return values as an indication of success.

Comment: I would strongly suggest just getting rid of all this code completely and use a pre-existing library, like libcurl, and let it handle the complexities of SSL/TLS, HTTP, etc for you.

Answer (score 3):

When you encounter some kind of transient network issue like this, you should do something sane rather than just aborting your program. Maybe you could wait a minute and then try again.

There are a lot of reasons this could happen. You may just happen to get routed to a server that can't handle your request at that moment. You may be temporarily rate-limited due to Google perceiving your connection storm as abuse. Your Internet connection may drop for a second or two. You may run out of local ephemeral ports.

You need to write code to handle these cases, and you haven't.

Also, one fine point. You don't call `bind`. This forces the `connect` call to do an implicit `bind` before the connection can be attempted. This is not good in an application like this for two reasons:

1. You have no control over the `bind` parameters. For example, you have no control over the local port.
2. If the `bind` fails, you will get an error from `connect`, making it harder to figure out the right response.

I would strongly urge you to explicitly call `bind`, choose the local port yourself, and sanely handle `bind` errors separately from `connect` errors.

Comment: @SW3RD Nope. Get a core dump (or run under a debugger) and see where it's faulting. There are a lot of possible explanations. If I had to guess, I'd say it's because you call `SSL_library_init` from multiple threads and the documentation explicitly says not to do this. You also modify the counter without holding the mutex that protects it. There are, to be honest, a lot of issues.

Comment: @SW3RD The program wouldn't wait for a minute, the thread would. But if that's not what you want to do when any of the conditions that I talked about happens, then you need to write code to detect those conditions and implement the handling that you do want. Your code has no error handling whatsoever except to abort the entire process on any error, no matter how minor or expected.

Comment: There is no need to call `bind`

Comment: @SW3RD I never said you *need* to call `bind`, but I explained two reasons why you *should* call `bind`.

Comment: @user253751 Then how will he handle local ephemeral port exhaustion? It's easy if you call `bind`, just pick a different local port. How do you suggest he do it without calling `bind`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How will you handle local non-ephemeral port exhaustion?

Comment: @user253751 That's much less likely given that there are usually at last ten times more non-ephemeral ports than ephemeral ports. But waiting or binding to a different local IP address (if possible) may be sensible strategies.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Running out of ephemeral ports is **also** extremely unlikely. But if you insist on handling extremely unlikely possibilities, why stop there?

Comment: @user253751 His code most likely *is* running out of ephemeral ports. You have to handle the situation *somehow*. He's asking his question because he hasn't handled cases like that and it's causing his code to fail.